# No fullscreen for opening PPS PowerPoint files

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, fullscreen

Is there any way to prevent the PowerPoint player from opening PPS file in fullscreen mode? Or is there a replacement for this player that can do this and is a full replacement for the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2010 Powerpoint Viewer application starts up windowed, but you would have to change file associations for .pps to the viewer kiosk software.

Available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cb9bf144-1076-4615-9951-294eeb832823)

Comment: Great! I was looking for such a long time exactly for this solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`.PPS` files open in full screen by nature. Change the extension of the file from `.PPS` to `.PPT`, and it will no more open in full screen mode.

Comment: Then I have to save the email attachment and rename it before opening. Your suggestion is a viable workaround, but unfortunately not convenient. Would like to have this behavior the default.