# How to play a PowerPoint slideshow as a normal window?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way to show a PowerPoint slideshow (.pps) as a normal window (and not in full screen)?

Comment: See the answer by Tog here: https://superuser.com/questions/232186/no-fullscreen-for-opening-pps-powerpoint-files

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the .pps attached to your computer (do not execute it)
2. Open independently your PowerPoint program
3. From PowerPoint, open the .pps you saved previously

Reference: http://solsie.com/2008/02/tip-open-pps-file-in-small-window/